# Return reference to temporary vector concatenation without copying

Tags: c++, c++14

Assume I have multiple vectors

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> v1;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> v2;
..
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> vn;
```

how can I perform an operation across all of them along the lines of without creating any copies

```
for (const auto& f : v1 + v2 + ... + vn)
{
    f->doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Since your vectors seem related, you can wrap them all in `std::array` and do a double for-loop, once over the array, then over the elements in that vector

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use C++20 ranges or [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) here is a simple option.

```
for (auto *target : { &v1, &v2, ..., &vn })
    for (const auto& f: *target)
    {
         f->doStuff();
    }
```