# Is there a way to concatenate 2 shared pointers without copying them?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I am basically wondering if there is a way to concatenate 2 `shared_ptr`'s into one without copying memory? The way I currently would concatenate them is:

```cpp
int main(){
  std::shared_ptr<float[]> _a = std::make_unique<float[]>(10);
  std::shared_ptr<float[]> _b = std::make_unique<float[]>(20);
  std::shared_ptr<float[]> concat = std::make_unique<float[]>(30);
  std::copy(_a.get(), _a.get() + 10, concat.get());
  std::copy(_b.get(), _b.get() + 20, concat.get() + 10);
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to just make a `shared_ptr` point to both on a certain range? I realize I could make a wrapper using the following:

```cpp
struct concat{
  std::shared_ptr<float[]> a;
  std::shared_ptr<float[]> b;
  size_t sa, sb;
  concat(std::shared_ptr<float[]> _a, std::shared_ptr<float[]> _b, size_t _sa, size_t _sb)
  :a(_a), b(_b), sa(_sa), sb(_sb)
{}
  float& operator[](const size_t& index){
  return (index > sa ? b[index - sa] : a[index]);
  }

};
```

Is there a more built-in way to do this with shared pointers?

Comment: Looks like you are making a `deque`. Can you just use `std::deque`?

Comment: Simplify the question. Is there any way to concatenate two pointers without copying them? Shared pointers add a kind of magic to general pointers, but it only extends to managing the lifetime of the pointed-at object.

Comment: Why would you want to concatenate *pointers*? Don't you mean concatenate what the pointers *point to*?

Comment: There is no way. You're likely looking for containers, not pointers. Like a `deque` or a rope. Pointers are generally very low-level primitive, they only point to random objects in memory with no semantics like "a sequence of objects" attached.

Comment: What is a concatenated pointer?  If you think of a pointer as an address or location of something, what does concatenation mean for an address or location?  Are you taking a location and appending another location?  For example, my address is 5 main street.  My buddy lives at 25 pine street.  Concatenating these addresses would result in "5 main street 25 pine street", which doesn't make sense.

Comment: You don't concatenate pointers - if pointers point at (the first element of) arrays, you concatenate the arrays.  In any event `shared_ptr<type[])` assumes it is managing a dynamically allocated *contiguous* array, and arrays managed by two distinct `shared_ptr`s are not necessarily contiguous.  So, in general, concatenating without copying (or moving) elements is not possible. To concatenate without copying, either use a different container that doesn't rely on contiguity, or mimic it somehow (e.g. wrap multiple `std::shared_ptr`s and take care of indexing, provide iterators, etc).

Comment: As in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76800155), you are conflating pointers with the things they point to. Your question is not really about "concatenate 2 shared pointers" but about "concatenate 2 arrays". On that note: [Return reference to temporary vector concatenation without copying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67328069) is a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, `std::shared_ptr` is designed to manage the lifetime of a heap-allocated object. When copying a `std::shared_ptr`, it does not copy the underlying object; rather, it increases the reference count. Therefore, if you want to concatenate two `std::shared_ptr` without copying the memory, you have to design a custom solution because the standard library does not support this directly.

The code you provided where you use a `struct` to wrap the two `std::shared_ptr` and override the `operator[]` is a good start. It provides an interface that mimics a single contiguous array. However, it does not create a `std::shared_ptr` that directly points to both arrays.

```cpp
struct concat{
  std::shared_ptr<float[]> a;
  std::shared_ptr<float[]> b;
  size_t sa, sb;
  concat(std::shared_ptr<float[]> _a, std::shared_ptr<float[]> _b, size_t _sa, size_t _sb)
  :a(_a), b(_b), sa(_sa), sb(_sb)
{}
  float& operator[](const size_t& index){
  return (index > sa ? b[index - sa] : a[index]);
  }
};
```

This solution is efficient because no memory copying is involved. However, it may not be as straightforward to use as a single `std::shared_ptr`. It depends on your specific use case whether this solution is suitable or not.

To answer your question, there is no built-in way to concatenate two `std::shared_ptr` without copying the memory in the standard library. Your custom solution seems to be the best approach for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, only the contrary is possible using the shared pointer aliasing feature with a unified buffer.

```
// unified buffer
// make shared more efficient for shared pointers
std::shared_ptr<float[]> concat = std::make_shared<float[]>(30);

// aliasing. Each shared pointer points to the same buffer but at different places
std::shared_ptr<float[]> _a = std::shared_ptr<float[]>(concat, &concat[0]);
std::shared_ptr<float[]> _b = std::shared_ptr<float[]>(concat, &concat[10]);
```